# Avoid a loop for integral2

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I have the following code:

```
Og = [4 3;3 4];
Oginv = inv(Og);

syms s1 s2
z = [s1 s2]*Oginv*[s1;s2];

fun  = matlabFunction(z*exp(-z/2));
cdf2 = integral2(fun,-inf,3,-inf,3, 'AbsTol', 1.e-6);
```

I want to evaluate it for different values of `Og` and different values of `xmax` and `ymax`, which in this particular case are `Og = [4 3;3 4]`, `xmax = 3`, `ymax = 3`. Is there any way how I can do it without a loop? I want to avoid a loop because I have a problem with the speed. I tried `cellfun`, but it does not help.

Comment: I would expect that most of the time is spent on `integral2`. Why do you think that avoiding a loop will make things faster?

Comment: @3lectrologos: maybe you are right... In the other hand for a group of variables I have that `Oginv` is different but `ymax` and `xmax` are tha same. I know that `integral` allows for array-valued functions. I tried to do the same with `integral2`, but I didn't succeed. Do you know whether this option is available?